# 2 actions in a row in componentDidMount not working synchronously in React / Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have 2 actions in componentDidMount:

- Action 1 initiates the state with dummy data.
- Action 2 filters the state.

But by the time action 2 happens, action 1 hasnt run yet for some reason so there's nothing to filter.

if I do a setTimeout on action 2 it fixes the problem, but thats not a good solution.

Here's the code:

```
componentDidMount() {

    const filterBy = this.props.collection.filterBy

    // Action 1
    this.props.collectionActions.loadRandomItems() 

    if (this.props.page == 'my-items') {

        console.log(this.props.collection.items) 

        // Action 2
        this.props.collectionActions.filter({ ...filterBy, amOwner: true}, this.props.collection.items) 
    }
}
```

Note that the console.log shows an empty array, but Action 1 should have loaded this array with items, so that Action 2 can use it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after `this.props.collectionActions.loadRandomItems()` your store is indeed updated. The thing is that your component needs to be re-rendered to get the new props. which means that in your `componentDidMount` this props points to the same old version of the props. `componentDidMount` is not a good place to handle updating of props. Use `componentWillReceiveProps`.

```
componentDidMount() {
    // Action 1
    this.props.collectionActions.loadRandomItems() 
}

componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
  if (newProps.page == 'my-items') {
    // Action 2
    const filterBy = newProps.collection.filterBy

    newProps.collectionActions.filter({ ...filterBy, amOwner: true}, this.props.collection.items) 
  }
}
```

Comment: I would add that moving the filtering code outside of the component would help remove some complexity, so that you pass in props that are ready for display. Since you're using react-redux, `mapStateToProps` would be a good place for that.